# Magento 2 Removing an inline translation from database

Tags: magento, magento2

An inline translation I did in Magento broke because I used a '&' symbol. Now, whenever I edit this translation nothing happends.

I want to remove the inline translation from the database, how would I do that?

The original text in the code shoudl be "Review & Payment"

Answer (score 4):

The inline translation is stored in the table `translation`. Use your favorite SQL client and delete the row from there.

```
select * from translation where string like '<orig string>%'
```

or

```
select * from translation where string like '<your bad text search>%'
```

and then

```
delete from translation where key_id = <taken from query above>
```

You need to either run the Magento command to redeploy statics or clean/flush caches to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score -2):

//Disable inline translation from admin and check.

`store->configuaration->Advanced Tab->Developer`->find "**Translate Inline**" option

Comment: This just turns on or off the ability to add in-line translations. As the OP said they'd already have added an in-line translation to the database, simply turning off the ability to add more will not prevent existing ones from being shown.